# Is the Russian expression "мне до ней далеко" grammatical?

Tags: падежи, местоимения

Is the Russian expression "мне до ней далеко" grammatical? And if so, what is this phenomenon called?

Answer (score 2):

> Is the Russian expression "мне до ней далеко" grammatical?

Yes, albeit colloquial.

*Ней* can replace the literary *неё* in the genitive most readily after *у*, but can be used after all prepositions governing the genitive.

> - Она чувствовала внутренний жар, как будто в груди у ней лежало раскаленное железо. [М. Ю. Лермонтов. Герой нашего времени (1839-1841)]
> - — От ней и башка небось не трещит, сколь ни пей? [Сергей Каледин. Записки гробокопателя (1987-1999)]
> - Не доходя до ней, он услышал с берегу знакомый голос: [Н. Г. Помяловский. Мещанское счастье (1860)]

Before 1900, *у ней* instead of *у неё* (*нея* in the pre-reform orthography) was widespread even in literature.

> If so, what is this phenomenon called?

Which phenomenon exactly?

Replacing literary words in common speech and discourses imitating common speech is called "colloquialism".

The tendency towards omitting sounds not crucial for conveying the meaning is called "relaxed speech".

Comment: нея is definitely not grammatical now

Comment: I did not mean whether it is a colloquialism, but rather whether it is a special form of genitive or what.

Comment: @Anixx: _ней_ is a colloquial way to form the genitive of _она_, most often used after _у_ but also after other prepositions. What exactly do you mean by "special"? _до ней_ and _до неё_ are semantically the same but stylistically different.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю так можно говорить, только чтобы упростить для себя задачу склонения местоимений. Однако в повседневной жизни, использование "ней" в пободном выражении, можно встретить редко. Обычно говорят и пишут "Мне до неё далеко".